# Realm 0.92 with swift get object at index

Tags: ios, swift, realm

i am new to realm with swift and just installed the new version of it and the objectAtIndex is not available like it used to be in the version before it. i am working with iOS 8 and Xcode 6 On realm 0.92 how do you get the object at index.

this is how i used to get it on realm .9

```
   var RealmX = RealmDB.allObjects()
   var RealmObject = RealmX.objectAtIndex(0) as! RealmDB
   println("\(RealmObject)")
```

i went through the documentation on realm, and can't seem to find the part where this is translated to the new version

Comment: Here it is in the new version http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries, @azuan is also correct on how you get the first object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just do it like this

```
var RealmObject = RealmX[0]
```

Comment: this didn't work, cause i am using 0.92 and does not have a member named 'allObjects'

Comment: @IOSFeng On that part, you can just use 'Realm().objects(RealmDB)'. They've changed the API. I had the same problem too few days ago